# Costs for sending ERC20 token

Tags: transactions, erc-20, fees

I want to move a small amount of OMG tokens to a different address. I have no ether at this address, so I guess I have to transfer some to this address in order to pay the transaction fee. If I want to send ~0.6 OMG, how do I calculate the transaction costs in ether?

Comment: and is it even worth it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send ERC20 tokens, you must sign a transaction. A transaction will use a certain amount of gas. Gas is sold at a per unit price.

The formula is

```
TransactionCost = gasUsed * gasPrice;
```

The `gasUsed` generally does not change regardless of how many tokens you send. **To send 1 token is the same price as to send 100 tokens**. The transaction will cost as much `gasUsed` as the ERC20 contract dictates; the `gasPrice` will be dictated by the load of the entire ethereum network.

You will have control over the `gasPrice`. However, a standard ERC20 token transfer's `gasUsed` will be "fixed" (or at least out of your control).

Higher `gasPrice` will mean faster transfers. Use https://ethgasstation.info/ to estimate transaction confirmation time.

If you are not in a hurry, choose a very low `gasPrice`.

Any unused gas is always refunded as per the Ethereum specification.

Comment: Got it now, thanks, this article also helped: https://steemit.com/ethereum/@tomshwom/ethereum-gas-how-it-works